# How to use Microsoft graph toolkit people picker with ASP.Net MVC web application?

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

Is there a documentation / Guidance on how to use Microsoft graph toolkit people picker with ASP.Net MVC web application?

Answer (score 0):

There are some key samples such as the main [repository](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/main/samples/proxy-provider-asp-net-mvc) one, which details most of the setup. You can also take a look at the documentation for the [proxy provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/proxy) since this most likely be your authentication method. You can also visit some of our favorite users/authors who've written some great [articles](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/a-lap-around-microsoft-graph-toolkit-day-11-microsoft-graph-toolkit-proxy-provider/) on usage.

Hope some of these help.